# ¿Como chequear si un índice existe en MongoDB, utilizando JAVA?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring, spring-boot, indexeddb

Tengo el siguiente código donde creo un índice:

```
collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("FECHA"), new IndexOptions().expireAfter(45L, TimeUnit.DAYS));
```

El problema es que si yo creo el índice manualmente me genera error en el log de JAVA diciendo que existe el índice FECHA_1.
También si detengo la aplicación y la vuelvo a encender me genera el mismo error.

Hay alguna funcion en JAVA, para poder comprobar si un indice existe?

Es decir, mi idea es algo como lo siguiente:

```
if(!indice.existe("FECHA")){
    collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("FECHA"), new IndexOptions().expireAfter(45L, TimeUnit.DAYS));
}
```

En una página encontré esto:

```
db.system.indexes.find({'name':'indexname'});
```

Pero cuando pongo `db.` no me sale la opción de system ni menos de indexes.
Entiendo que ese código es para la terminal de **mongodb** pero quisiera algo similar para JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es [`collection.listIndexes()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#listIndexes()), que te devolverá un iterable con la lista de todos los índices de tu colección.

Por ejemplo podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```java
private boolean existIndex(String indexName, MongoCollection<Document> collection) {
  for (final Document doc : collection.listIndexes()) {
    if (doc.getString("name").equals(indexName)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Con esta función puedes obtener un valor booleano que será verdadero si el nombre del índice que pasas como argumento existe en la colección que pasas como argumento.

En la misma uso el método [`getString()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/bson/org/bson/BsonDocument.html#getString(java.lang.Object)) del Objeto `BSON`.

Luego lo puedes implementar como gustes:

```java
if(!existsIndex(<index_name>, collection)){
    collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("FECHA"), new IndexOptions().expireAfter(45L, TimeUnit.DAYS));
}
```

Una acotación, en MongoDB los nombres de los índices no son igual al nombre del campo seleccionado como tal.

Si tu decides establecer un índice ascendente (1) sobre el campo 'FECHA', el nombre del mismo será:

```
FECHA_1
```

Si lo haces de forma descendente (-1) el nombre del índice será:

```
FECHA_-1
```

En tu caso particular puedes hacer la consulta así:

```java
if(!existsIndex("FECHA_1", collection)){
    collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("FECHA"), new IndexOptions().expireAfter(45L, TimeUnit.DAYS));
}
```

Para mayor información puedes consultar la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#index-names).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: mil gracias! Me funcionó como esperaba!